# how to display sub menus when hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a vertical menu like this :

```
<ul>
<li>Level 1 menu
    <ul>
       <li>Level 2 item</li>
       <li>Level 2 item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Level 1 menu
    <ul>
       <li>Level 2 item</li>
       <li>Level 2 item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Level 1 menu</li>
</ul>
```

Now i need to display the Level 2 items once i hover so i added this line

```
#bar  ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

in css but it didn't make any difference, and i have no other display tag in my css

```
#bar ul { list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
#bar ul li { padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px; }
#bar ul li a {  color: #FFF; font-size: 16px;    }
#bar ul li a:hover { font-weight:bold }
#bar ul li ul li { padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px; margin-left:10px;}
#bar ul li ul li a { padding-left: 0px; font-size: 10px;   }
```

Comment: Can you post a demo? And add the code you use to hide submenus? And try using child selectors `>` (which are faster) with descendant ones wisely used. But a 5 level descendant selector is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand right, you need to add `#bar ul li ul { display: none; }`

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KA3eL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#bar  ul li ul { display: none;}
#bar  ul li:hover ul { display: block; }
```

and also wrap your lists in element with id `#bar`

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMbj4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using child selectors `>` (which are faster) with descendant ones wisely used. But a 5 level descendant selector is overkill.

Basically, first use a single descendant selector to affect all of them, and then a child one to override and set styles for the first level.

Something like this:

```css
#menu { list-style: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
#menu li { padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px; margin-left:10px; }
#menu > li { padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px; margin-left:0; }
#menu a { color: #FFF; padding-left: 0px; font-size: 10px; }
#menu > li > a { font-size: 16px; }
#menu a:hover { font-weight:bold }
#menu ul { display: none; }
#menu li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tNL9V/)